# Images only resize in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, image, cross-browser, responsive-design

I have a set of images that should resize according to what the current window size the browser is. This is set by the CSS properties;

```
#photoframe {
    white-space:nowrap;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
    }

#photoframe img {
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    }
```

Now this works using chrome but not any other browser.

**Example**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q273/4/)

This example works in chrome and does exactly what i need, however this example does not work in IE or Firefox?

**My Code**

Someone may find this useful.

Full HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="fluid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>
<body>
<div id="title">
  <h1>Bass Clef Photography</h1>
</div>
<div id="tagline">Passion 4 Live Music &amp; Passion 4 Photography</div>
<div id="tabsContainer">
<div id="centerContainer">
 <div class='tab zero'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="BassClef.html">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
    <div class='tab one'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Music Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab two'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab three'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab four'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab five'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="photoframeContainer">
  <div id="photoframe">
    <img src="uploads/picture01.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="uploads/picture02.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="uploads/picture03.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="uploads/picture04.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="uploads/picture05.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="uploads/picture06.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="uploads/picture07.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="uploads/picture08.jpg" alt="">
  </div>


</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Full CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width: 100%;
}
body, html{
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#424242;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;



}

H1{
margin:0;   
}
/*
    Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
    ----------------------------------
    dw-num-cols-mobile:     5;
    dw-num-cols-tablet:     8;
    dw-num-cols-desktop:    10;
    dw-gutter-percentage:   25;

    Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
    http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

    and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
    http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

#tabsContainer {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    top: 240px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;

}
#centerContainer {
    width: 230px;
    height: 280px;
    clear: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#tabsContainer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 17px 15px 0 15px;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 200px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #d3701e;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li #active a {
    color: #d3701e;
    background: url(images/navigation-hover.png) repeat-x left top;
}
.tab {
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    clear: both;
}
.tab.one {
    width: 220px auto;
    font-size: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 87.36%;
    padding-left: 1.82%;
    padding-right: 1.82%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#title {
    clear: both;
    float: left;

    top:0;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
#tagline {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    top:100px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #d3701e;
}

#photoframeContainer{

    bottom:0px;


}
#photoframe {
    white-space:nowrap;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;

    }

#photoframe img {
    height:70%;
    width:auto;
    /*max-width:100%;
    min-width:100px;*/
}




/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */


@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 90.675%;
    padding-left: 1.1625%;
    padding-right: 1.1625%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#title {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    top:0px;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#tagline {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    top:140px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
#tabsContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    top:200px;

}
#centerContainer {
    width: 460px;
    height: 150px;
    clear: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#tabsContainer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 17px 15px 0 15px;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #d3701e;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li #active a {
    color: #d3701e;
    background: url(images/navigation-hover.png) repeat-x left top;
}
.tab {
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    clear: none;
}
.tab.one {
    width: 220px auto;
    font-size: 24px;
}
}


/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 88.2%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0.9%;
    padding-right: 0.9%;
    margin: auto;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#title {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    top:0px;

    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
#tagline {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    top:130px;

    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
#tabsContainer {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    top: 160px;

    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;


}
#centerContainer {
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#tabsContainer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 17px 15px 0 15px;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: auto;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #d3701e;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li #active a {
    color: #d3701e;
    background: url(images/navigation-hover.png) repeat-x left top;
}
.tab {
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    clear: none;
}
.tab.one {
    width: 190px;
    font-size: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
}
```

Comment: inline elements dont have width and height, it gets determined by the content. images are inline by default. chrome will do "nice" things like display inline elements with block children, or inline elements with height and width, as though they were inline block. try making your images `display:inline-block;` and see if that works better

Comment: @chiliNUT, Unfortunately it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using vw i vh?

vw is viewing width, and vh is viewing height. It's similar to percentage, but it always depends on screen user is using. width:50vw; is like 50% of viewing width.

And when you apply that to images, they will resize depending on width of a screen, not a parental div, so maybe it will work for you.

Sorry for too short answer at first.